# Simple page hit counter with Nuxt 3 using an API

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am trying to setup a simple page hit counter with Nuxt 3 using an API.

This is my template code:

```
// components/TheHeader.vue

<template>
    <header>
        <div class="counter">
            <div id="visits">0005024</div>
        </div>
    </header>
</template>

<script setup>
    const { data: count } = await useFetch('https://api.countapi.xyz/hit/$website.com.au/$apikeyXXXXXXXXX?callback=websiteVisits');

    setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector("#visits").textContent = count.value;
        console.log(count.value);
    }, 500);
</script>
```

I am new to Nuxt JS and am trying to adapt [this tutorial](https://codepen.io/mignunez/pen/yLzYOEz) to work with this Nuxt website. I am referencing [this documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching) on data fetching.

This is the data that it returns, which is printing in the DOM:

`/**/ typeof websiteVisits === 'function' && websiteVisits({"code":200,"value":136});`

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to extract and print the "value" only ('136') with Javascript? Not sure if I am going about this the right way?

Thank you in advance and sorry for the novice question, I'm still learning !!